# Uncaught ReferenceError - Javascript in Jekyll project

Tags: javascript, html, coffeescript, jekyll, bourbon

I'm using Jekyll for this project.

- Is the below directory structure correct for a standard Jekyll project
- I've created a javascript folder in assets. With a coffeescript file in the folder
- Do I need to @import / @include this javascript file in the `index.html` which the js is for ?

**Directory Structure**

```
/project
  /.sass-cache
  /_includes
  /_layouts
  /_posts
  /_sass
  /_site
  /about
  /assets
    /images
      picture.png
      nextpicture.jpeg
    /js
      welcome.coffee
  /build
  /buld
  /css
  /serve
  .gitignore
  _config.yml
  feed.xml
  index.html
  nextpage.html
```

---

**index.html**

- This is the homepage content with a tabbed ul list as the main content
- This tabbed ul list is a Bourbon Refills Pattern called accordion-tabs-minimal

**home page**

```
---
layout: welcome
---

<div class="home">


 <h1>Title</h1>

 <ul class="accordion-tabs-minimal">
  <li class="tab-header-and-content">
    <a href="#" class="tab-link is-active">Tab Item</a>
    <div class="tab-content">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras tincidunt pellentesque lorem, id suscipit dolor rutrum id. Morbi facilisis porta volutpat. Fusce adipiscing, mauris quis congue tincidunt, sapien purus suscipit odio, quis dictum odio tortor in sem. Ut sit amet libero nec orci mattis fringilla. Praesent eu ipsum in sapien tincidunt molestie sed ut magna. Nam accumsan dui at orci rhoncus pharetra tincidunt elit ullamcorper. Sed ac mauris ipsum. Nullam imperdiet sapien id purus pretium id aliquam mi ullamcorper.</p>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="tab-header-and-content">
    <a href="#" class="tab-link">Another Tab</a>
    <div class="tab-content">
      <p>Ut laoreet augue et neque pretium non sagittis nibh pulvinar. Etiam ornare tincidunt orci quis ultrices. Pellentesque ac sapien ac purus gravida ullamcorper. Duis rhoncus sodales lacus, vitae adipiscing tellus pharetra sed. Praesent bibendum lacus quis metus condimentum ac accumsan orci vulputate. Aenean fringilla massa vitae metus facilisis congue. Morbi placerat eros ac sapien semper pulvinar. Vestibulum facilisis, ligula a molestie venenatis, metus justo ullamcorper ipsum, congue aliquet dolor tortor eu neque. Sed imperdiet, nibh ut vestibulum tempor, nibh dui volutpat lacus, vel gravida magna justo sit amet quam. Quisque tincidunt ligula at nisl imperdiet sagittis. Morbi rutrum tempor arcu, non ultrices sem semper a. Aliquam quis sem mi.</p>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="tab-header-and-content">
    <a href="#" class="tab-link">Third</a>
    <div class="tab-content">
      <p>Donec mattis mauris gravida metus laoreet non rutrum sem viverra. Aenean nibh libero, viverra vel vestibulum in, porttitor ut sapien. Phasellus tempor lorem id justo ornare tincidunt. Nulla faucibus, purus eu placerat fermentum, velit mi iaculis nunc, bibendum tincidunt ipsum justo eu mauris. Nulla facilisi. Vestibulum vel lectus ac purus tempus suscipit nec sit amet eros. Nullam fringilla, enim eu lobortis dapibus, quam magna tincidunt nibh, sit amet imperdiet dolor justo congue turpis.</p>    
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="tab-header-and-content">
    <a href="#" class="tab-link">Last Item</a>
    <div class="tab-content">
      <p>Sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Phasellus dui urna.</p>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>


  <p class="rss-subscribe">subscribe <a href="{{ "/feed.xml" | prepend: site.baseurl }}">via RSS</a></p>

</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/js/welcome.js"></script>
```

---

**/assets/js/welcome.coffee**

- The javascript is for the welcome page but it comes up with **Undefined Reference Error**
- I used inspect element in the chrome browser to see that problem with js

**js**

```
---
---

$(document).ready ->
  $(".accordion-tabs-minimal").each (index) ->
    $(this).children("li").first().children("a").addClass("is-active").next().addClass("is-open").show()
    return

  $(".accordion-tabs-minimal").on "click", "li > a", (event) ->
    unless $(this).hasClass("is-active")
      event.preventDefault()
      accordionTabs = $(this).closest(".accordion-tabs-minimal")
      accordionTabs.find(".is-open").removeClass("is-open").hide()
      $(this).next().toggleClass("is-open").toggle()
      accordionTabs.find(".is-active").removeClass "is-active"
      $(this).addClass "is-active"
    else
      event.preventDefault()
    return

  return
```

**Issues**

So, the javascript isn't linking to the html file correctly. What is this undefined reference error?

**Upon Inspect Element**

`Uncaught: ReferenceError: $ is not defined`

**Objectives**

- The javascript controls the display of paragraph text on click of [bourbon refills](http://refills.bourbon.io/) accordion tab

Currently, the tabs display no information because they are `display: none;` until javascript calls `.show()`

Answer (score 1):

The `$` is used in jquery

Remember to include the following in your `head.html`

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```